# How to access firefox web console command history?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox

It is fairly easy to access the last 30 (!) javascript console commands in Google Chrome devtools:

Undock devtools and press `Ctrl`+`Shift`+`I` in it to inspect devtools itself.

In that new devtools window, type following commands in the console:

```js
> location.origin
"chrome-devtools://devtools"
> JSON.parse(localStorage.consoleHistory).join('\n')
"inp.style.backgroundColor = "rgb(250, 0, 250)"
inp.style.backgroundColor = "rgb(250, 255, 250)"
...
inp.style.backgroundSize
inp.style.backgroundColor"
> JSON.parse(localStorage.consoleHistory).length
30
```

How can I do the equivalent in Firefox?

I wouldn't mind if it had a longer command history than google chrome.

That pastebin answer was only good for a day. So here it is again, thanks @msucan!

```js
function getWebConsolePanel(tab) {
    var gDevTools = Cu.import("resource:///modules/devtools/gDevTools.jsm", {})\
.gDevTools;
    var tools = Cu.import("resource://gre/modules/devtools/Loader.jsm", {}).dev\
tools;
    var target = tools.TargetFactory.forTab(tab || gBrowser.selectedTab);
    var toolbox = gDevTools.getToolbox(target);
    var panel = toolbox.getPanel("webconsole");
    return panel;
}

getWebConsolePanel();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Press <kbd>F12</kbd> to open the developer toolbox (eg. the web console), then
2. Switch to the Options panel.
3. Enable chrome debugging.
4. Open Scratchpad (<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>F4</kbd>).
5. Copy/paste this code: https://pastebin.mozilla.org/3757211
6. Go to Environment > Browser.
7. Pick Execute > Display or Inspect.

And now you will see the web console history for the currently selected tab.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!
For `Display` I only get `/* */` .
For `Inspect` I get a panel with the expected history put I cannot copy/paste those element's text.
So I can't really get at that history.
Is there a way to print those entries to the console or a HTML div or such?

Comment: Yes. `getWebConsoleHistory().toString()` then the *Display* option will give you the array elements stringified.

Comment: The pastebin link is dead

Answer (score 2):

**Updated instructions based on @msucan's answer**

1. Press <kbd>F12</kbd> to open the web console
2. Open the Developer Tools Settings (<kbd>F1</kbd>)
3. Check "Enable browser chrome and add-on debugging toolboxes" and "Enable remote debugging"
4. Open the [Browser Toolbox](https://firefox-source-docs.mozilla.org/devtools-user/browser_toolbox/index.html) (`Ctrl-Alt-Shift-I`) and click Ok.
5. Copy/paste this code:

```js
async function getWebConsolePanel(tab) {
  const { require } = ChromeUtils.import("resource://devtools/shared/loader/Loader.jsm");
  const devtools = require("devtools/client/framework/devtools").gDevTools;
  var toolbox = await devtools.getToolboxForTab(tab || gBrowser.selectedTab);
  var panel = toolbox.getPanel("webconsole");
  return panel;
}
```

6. You can then access the history as an array using

   - `(await getWebConsolePanel()).hud.ui.wrapper.getStore().getState().history.entries;`

(note: a web console needs to be open on the open tab)

---

Relevant links:

[gDevTools is now a commonjs module](https://github.com/mozilla/gecko-dev/commit/8178c87f2be4b22efb87501e205c725f3b1fe679). [bugzilla discussion](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1188405)

[How to get history from console panel](https://searchfox.org/mozilla-central/source/devtools/client/webconsole/test/browser/browser_jsterm_history_persist.js#29)

[getHistoryEntries function definition](https://searchfox.org/mozilla-central/source/devtools/client/webconsole/selectors/history.js#17)

Comment: I imagine it's also stored somewhere in the sqlite file, any idea where?

Comment: [profile folder]/storage/permanent/indexeddb+++fx-devtools/idb/[...].sqlite

I was able find it by running in a unique command in the console (`console.log("unique1234")`), then in the my system console running:
`grep -rlw "unique123" ~/.mozilla/firefox/`

Comment: thanks I know where the sqlite file is as I used it in the past but I meant, and apologies for the unclear question, where specifically in the DB, like what tables because AFAIK there are quite a few and I'm not sure how to do FTS across all tables.

Comment: Well, it's not a normal database. Technically it is stored as a binary blob in one of the records of the "data" field of the "object_table" table. The data is designed to be accessed using the [IndexedDB API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API/Using_IndexedDB). (usable from the Browser Toolbox). See [this page](https://searchfox.org/mozilla-central/source/devtools/shared/async-storage.js) for reference for how Firefox accesses it.

Comment: You can also just import async-storage.js and use it like [history-persistence does](https://searchfox.org/mozilla-central/source/devtools/client/webconsole/middleware/history-persistence.js):
`const { require: devtoolsRequire, loader } = ChromeUtils.importESModule(
  "resource://devtools/shared/loader/Loader.sys.mjs"
);
loader.lazyRequireGetter(
  this,
  "asyncStorage",
  "resource://devtools/shared/async-storage.js"
);
let webConsoleHistory = await asyncStorage.getItem("webConsoleHistory");`

Comment: [This file](https://searchfox.org/mozilla-central/source/devtools/server/actors/storage.js) could be helpful if you are trying to reimplement the way Firefox decodes the sqlite file in an external program.